# Authenticating Google Cloud Datastore c# SDK

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to authenticate Google Datastore c# SDK in a k8 pod running in google cloud.
I could not find any way to inject the account.json file in to DatastoreDb or DatastoreClient beside using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
Using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is problematic since i do not want to leave the account file exposed.

According to the documentations in: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/index.html

> When running on Google Cloud Platform, no action needs to be taken to
>   authenticate.

But that does not seem to work.

A push in the right direction will be  appreciated (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
    var credential = 
 GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"/path/to/google.credentials.json").CreateScoped(DatastoreClient.DefaultScopes);
    var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(DatastoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

    DatastoreClient client = DatastoreClient.Create(channel, settings: 
    DatastoreSettings.GetDefault());
    DatastoreDb db = DatastoreDb.Create(YOUR_PROJECT_ID, client:client);
    // Do Datastore stuff...
    // Shutdown the channel when it is no longer required.
    await channel.ShutdownAsync();
```

Taken from: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/DatastoreClient.cs

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a K8s secret to store the service account key and then mounting it in the pod at run time. See below:

1. Create a service account for the desired application.
2. Generate and encode a service account key: just generate a `.json` key for the newly created service account from the previous step and then encode it using `base64 -w 0 key-file-name`. This is important: K8S expects the secret's content to be Base64 encoded.
3. Create the K8s secret manifest file (see content below) and then apply it.

   `apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: your-service-sa-key-k8s-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
      sa_json: previously_generated_base64_encoding`
4. Mount the secret.

   > ```
   >    volumes:
   >  - name: service-account-credentials-volume
   >    secret:
   >      secretName: your-service-sa-key-k8s-secret
   >      items:
   >      - key: sa_json
   >        path: secrets/sa_credentials.json
   > ```

Now all you have to do is set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CRENDENTIALS to be secrets/sa_credentials.json.

Hope this helps. Sorry for the formatting (on a hurry).

Comment: This is what i ended up doing before asking the question. Unfortunately this does not meet the security specification i work under since the account file end up as un encrypted  on the pod file system. (the k8 term secret is misleading) I appreciate the advise @Andrei Balici

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/. Never actually done it, but maybe it's a starting point for you.